# jQuery Mobile: alternative of .trigger('create') or .page() when updating navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile

I have the following jQuery Mobile HTML code, the navbar's content is set using javascript. jQuery mobile styles the navbar when it's set statically, but when you set the content of it (html) later using javascript, you have to do some extra work to make it work:

```
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 id="title">App</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content">    
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
            <ul id="menu">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

`trigger('create');` is generally used to solve the problem of unstyled markup when set using javascript/ajax. *However*, it seems only to work within `data-role="content"` and not for `#navbar`. The script below should work but leaves the menu unstyled...

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu").html("<li><a href='#'>Test Styling</a></li>").trigger('create');
});
```

Any ideas how to solve this? I have tried `page();` and `.listview('refresh');` with no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling the `navbar` method after appending the list item:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu").html("<li><a href='#'>Test Styling</a></li>");
    $("#navbar").navbar(); 
});
```

**Edit:**
You could also try creating the navbar dynamically :

```
var footer = $("#footer-id");

var navBar = $("div", {
    "data-role":"navbar",
    "html":"<ul><li><a href='#'>Test Styling</a></li></ul>"
}).appendTo(footer).navbar();
```

Comment: I will try this again tomorrow morning but right now it seems to raise an error: `no such method 'refresh' for navbar widget` when doing `$("#navbar").navbar("refresh");` and `$("#navbar").navbar();` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. The specific moment the JavaScript is executed is important! Had to run it after the DOM was loaded obviously..

Comment: Hi, anything else u had to do? this wont work for me, it wont load the classes for the <li><a> elements that are create dinamically.