# Dynamic navbar not enhanced on first page of multi-page document

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically creating the navbar in my multi-page document. My problem is that the navbar is not enhanced on the first page in the document, but - strangely - on every other page. The kicker is that if I add a page in the code before this actual first page and set up an event to forward to the "actual" first page, everything works fine. The code for the navbar is the same everywhere for now:

```
<div data-role="page" id="stdPage" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="content">
        ...
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="persFooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div>
```

I'm populating the navbar on all the pages using:

```
$(function () {
    $("div[data-role='navbar'] ul").empty();
    $("div[data-role='navbar'] ul").append("<li><a href=\"#stdPage\" data-icon=\"home\">Test</a></li>");
    $("div[data-role='navbar']").navbar();
});
```

When doing this, as I said, the navbar on the first page - the one already on display - is not enhanced. All the other pages have enhanced navbars.

I've tried messing around with .page() and trigger("pagecreate") etc. to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your navbar needs to be in the page when the 'pageinit' event fires the first time your browswer loads that page.  This is when jQ Mobile enhances the content of your page.

It sounds like you're adding the navbars to your whole document after the 'pageinit' event fires on your first page. This is why when you navigate to any other page, it fires 'pageinit' and enhances your content properly.

What you should try is copying your common header on the 'mobileinit' event, copying it before jQuery mobile loads (put the script you're using before the jQ Mobile script tag), or put your header's markup on your first page and copy clones (.clone()) to everypage after the markup is enhanced.

As for the trigger the proper syntax is this:  `$(yourelement).trigger('create')`.

```
$(function () {
    $("div[data-role='navbar'] ul").empty();
    $("div[data-role='navbar'] ul").append("<li><a href=\"#stdPage\" data-icon=\"home\">Test</a></li>");
    $("div[data-role='navbar']").trigger('create');

});
```

Good luck!

**FOLLOW UP:**  Here's how I did it.

I had a header that I wanted to make common to certain pages on of which was my first page.  So I made the header on that front page as I normally would.  On my other pages I put a placeholder div with a `class="commonHeader"`.

Then on 'mobileinit' I added the following instruction:

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function(event){
        $('.commonHeader').each(function(index, element) { //attach common header to all pages
             $(element).replaceWith($('#frontPage [data-role="header"]').clone(true, true));     
        });
});
```

You can try using the same method only on the pages you need common header.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried binding to pageinit and mobileinit, but nothing helped. Using the correct create trigger didn't, either. I'm reluctant to use the clone() option because I will ultimately require different headers on every page.

Comment: Try binding to the 'pagebeforecreate' event.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I tried your further suggestions but sadly none of them work. The clone method fails because the pages besides the one being display upon page load are not enhanced until they are called. Judging from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214487/jquery-mobile-alternative-of-triggercreate-or-page-when-updating-navbar) the .navbar() function called on the parent div is supposed to and used to work, but doesn't anymore. I'm going to report this as a bug. Binding to _pagebeforecreate_ works on the first page, but somehow breaks all the others. Weird.

Comment: Ok I just setup your markup and your code here and it seems to work fine, however I can reproduce the symptoms you've described if I put the javascript AFTER I call jQuery mobile.  You're supposed to put your code and binding BEFORE you call jQuery mobile that way your markup and event listeners are there before jQM starts enhancing markup.  Is this the case?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, this is a silly problem with one of those *duh* solutions that I really want to help you solve so we can both have that satisfying "aha!' moment....

Comment: What I've tried is binding to mobileinit (with .on()) before JQM is loaded and manipulating the navbar div at that moment - but it turns out the DOM isn't loaded and the div doesn't exist yet. If I bind to pageinit before loading JQM the problem persists. I've tried binding to several events. If I bind to _pagebeforecreate_ before loading JQM, the first page shows the navbar but with incorrect styling, all subsequent pages are broken, then the first one gets broken when navigating back to it. This is starting to become a WTF thing. What event did you bind to?

Comment: Don't bind, in your case here I just put your function as is AFTER jQuery and BEFORE jQM, that way it changed the DOM immediately and therefore before any jQM events fired.

Comment: Dear God - it works. Sort of. The navbar doesn't inherit the theme specific in <div data-role="footer">. Theming only works if I actually put data-theme in the added <a> items. Not sure why this is, but thanks a million times. _Duh!_